# Exact word or phrase for the following situation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the exact word/phrase for following kind of behaviour?

One person has already been to a crowded place and the person thinks that he is highly likely already caught the covid virus infection from there (no symptoms yet or has not tested positive). Now this person does not wash hand with soap saying that he has already done riskier things and what is point in washing his hand with soap or follow any precaution any more.

I would like to know what this kind of mentality is called when a person thinks (there is no proof that his thoughts are hundred percentage accurate) everything has already gone bad so it's ok they can do anything even if that can make the situation even worse.

Comment: Fatalistic? Hypochondriac? Cultivating Munchausen? Cursing the darkness but won't light a candle?

Comment: Might not be linguistically accurate, but I would call them _**irresponsible**_.

Comment: If 'everything has already gone bad…' why should anyone care, or act responsibly?

Deluging the point in details misled me into thinking 'careless' or 'irresponsible' or 'reckless' should apply but if everything has already gone bad, don't 'desperation' or 'fatality' take their place?

Either way, how could it matter whether those thoughts were accurate, unless you're suggesting that motivation is always irrelevant?

Answer (score 2):

They are **reckless**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reckless)
> *reckless*
> doing something dangerous and not worrying about the risks and the possible results

They are also **heedless**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heedless)
> *heedless*
> not giving attention to a risk or possible difficulty

and lastly, they are **foolhardy**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foolhardy)
> *foolhardy*
> brave in a silly way, taking unnecessary risks:

These are the most relevant adjectives. Less appropriate and more condemnatory would be *witless*, *mindless* and *thoughtless*.

Comment: I would generally use "Reckless" for one who drives dangerously, "Heedless" fo one who does not think a good advice over and "Foolhardy" for one who tries to push a big stone up on a steep incline.